# Core Data is returning 0

Tags: swift, core-data

**Update:** Following some advice from the comments, I am using `NSManagedObject Subclassing`. So my code is completely different so I am rewriting the question to better reflect what I am doing now.

So my question is: **I am saving non-zero values to Core Data, but when I retrieve a value I am getting zero back. What could be wrong?**

So now let's pretend I have two entities named `FirstEntity, SecondEntity` with two attributes named `firstAttribute, secondAttribute`. And since I did the NSManagedObject Subclassing I have two classes one named `FirstEntity` and the second named `SecondEntity`. Each class has an extension for the two attributes (`firstAttribute`, `secondAttribute`).

**Saving Values:**
So when I save a value I would use code along the lines of:

```
let number = 100
let firstEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("FirstEntity", inManagedObjectContext: managedObject) as! FirstEntity
firstEntity.firstAttribute = number
```

**Retrieving Values:** When I try to receive an attribute's value in Core Data I use code like this:

```
let firstEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("FirstEntity", inManagedObjectContext: managedObject) as! FirstEntity
print(firstEntity.firstAttribute) // This returns zero when I clearly saved a value of 100 above.
```

*I am pretty new to Core Data, and I have looked up many examples of how to use Core Data online. I am still kind of confused about what I could possibly be doing wrong. If there is any clarification required just ask in the comments, and I will definitely respond.*

**Potential Error:** So what I am doing is I am trying to save an attributes value in the `completionHandler` of a function. Also, if I print the variable's value inside the `completionHandler` I get the proper value of the attribute. For example:

```
someFunction() {
    number in // Pretend number is 5000
    let firstEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("FirstEntity", inManagedObjectContext: managedObject) as! FirstEntity
    firstEntity.firstAttribute = number
    print(firstEntity.firstAttribute) // Prints 5000 to the console
}
```

However, let's say I go to access the `firstAttribute` value outside of the `completionHandler` and I print the value to the console I get a value of 0. For example:

```
class MyClass {
    func myFunction() {
        let firstEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("FirstEntity", inManagedObjectContext: managedObject) as! FirstEntity
    print(firstEntity.firstAttribute) // Prints 0
    }
}
```

*I also wanted to mention that I am making sure that the completionHandler in the function has set the value of the firstAttribute before calling the MyClass's myFunction().*

Comment: What is the type of firstAttribute?, also show how you are calling saveData?

Comment: Are you positive their values are not zero because you've looked in the database? And if you're using a model, why aren't you using the generated classes (StepCount, ActiveEntergy, etc.)?

Comment: @Shripada The type of firstAttribute is Integer 16

Comment: What value you have set to it?

Comment: @Michael Thanks for your comment! I am really new to CoreData so may I ask What are the generated classes?

Comment: @Shripada I set it to 100 just for debugging purposes.

Comment: try print(firstEntityCD[0]) and see whats happening

Comment: @Johnykutty This is what I get `<NSManagedObject: 0x7fbb5b80e4d0> (entity: firstEntity; id: 0xd000000000040002 <x-coredata://2416F451-B757-4807-BAC2-9B462A4B0A26/firstEntity/p1> ; data: <fault>)`

Comment: firstEntity is correct name or just sample name of the Entity? because xcode won't allow you to add an entity starting with lowercase letter

Comment: @Johnykutty it's a sample name, let me change it to FirstEntity to avoid confusion...

Comment: I copied your code and its working fine for me, may be somethig else you are doing wron

Comment: You can generate Swift classes for your model by selecting "Editor > Create NSManagedObject Subclass". Don't forget to tell it you want Swift code. Xcode will create a separate Swift file for each entity in the model with properties for each entity's attributes. Then instead of `managedObject.valueForKey("myAttribute")` you can just use `entityName.myAttribute`.

Comment: Add this Application supports iTunes to your app, and take a look at the saved data on the iPad itself. You should be able to find the core database files you saved on it.

Comment: @Michael Great I will try that as soon as I get home! Also how would I save to Core Data using an NSManagedObject Subclass?

Comment: Saving is no different with a subclass. You just update all the properties and save the managed object context.

Comment: @Michael ok great I will try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I think I found the answer I was creating too many instances of the entity. So what I ended up doing was I created a global constant:

```
let firstEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("FirstEntity", inManagedObjectContext: managedObject) as! FirstEntity
```

Then I referenced `firstEntity` whenever I needed to retrieve or save a value so I didn't have multiple instances of `FirstEntity`. Then I can access the value from anywhere.